# Any quick fix to uninstall vs 2012 completely

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 RC - ENU
Fatal error during installation.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools RC enu Language Pack
Package failed.

Microsoft Visual Studio Preparation
The system cannot find the file specified

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC XAML UI Designer Core
Package failed. 
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 RC Team Explorer Language Pack - ENU
Package failed.

Comment: You'll want to give much more detail about how you're trying the uninstall, and what your installation history was.